# Implementing HTML5 canvas gradients in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create an app that lets you create a background gradient with two different colors,I'm using React. The first color of the gradient looks as it should, but the second color of the gradient is more of a solid color, with a jagged border. Heres a picture to demonstrate: [image]

My goal is to get something that closer resembles to this: 
[image]

Where the colors blend.

I'm referring to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) docs , and have messed around with the radius and x, y properties. I'm changing the canvas based on prop changes from the parent component, here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Canvas extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { gradientOne, gradientTwo } = this.props.canvasState.backgroundColor;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.radialGradient = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
      0,
      0,
      300,
      260,
      160,
      100
    );

    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.radialGradient;
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.radialGradient.addColorStop(0, gradientOne);
    this.radialGradient.addColorStop(1, gradientTwo);
    this.ctx.fill();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { gradientOne, gradientTwo } = this.props.canvasState.backgroundColor;
    if (prevProps.canvasState.backgroundColor.gradientOne !== gradientOne) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.radialGradient;
      this.radialGradient.addColorStop(0, gradientOne);
      this.ctx.fill();
    } else if (
      prevProps.canvasState.backgroundColor.gradientTwo !== gradientTwo
    ) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.radialGradient;
      this.radialGradient.addColorStop(1, gradientTwo);
      this.ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="canvasContainer">
        <canvas ref={ref => (this.canvas = ref)} id="canvas">
          YOUR BROWSER DOESN'T SUPPORT THIS FEATURE :(
        </canvas>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Canvas;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color stops of CanvasGradient (be it linear or radial) can't be modified nor removed.
When you add a new color stop, at the same index than a previous one, it gets placed right after that previous one. So instead of having only two color stops, you have four.

This means that if you have an original gradient like so

```
 <-red -------------------------------------------- green->
```

and that you add two new color stops `blue` and `yellow` at position `0` and `1`, you will have something like

```
 <-red[blue -------------------------------- green]yellow->
```

That is, no gradient between red and blue, nor between yellow and green:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
// an horizontal gradient
// 0 is at pixel 50, and 1 at pixel 250 on the x axis
const grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(50,0,250,0);
grad.addColorStop(0, 'red');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'green');
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
// top is two color stops version
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,70);

// bottom is four color stops version
grad.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'yellow');
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fillRect(0,80,300,70);

//  mark color stops
ctx.moveTo(49.5,0);
ctx.lineTo(49.5,150);
ctx.moveTo(249.5,0);
ctx.lineTo(249.5,150);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid };
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

That's what you are doing in your code, since you add two color stops in `componentDidMount`, and then add more in `componentDidUpdate`.

To avoid this, simply overwrite your `gradient` property in `componentDidUpdate`, so that you start everytime with a new gradient.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let radialGradient;
function didMount() {
  radialGradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    0,0,300,
    260,160,100
   );
  radialGradient.addColorStop(0, c1.value);
  radialGradient.addColorStop(1, c2.value);
  ctx.fillStyle = radialGradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
function didUpdate() {
  // reset radialGradient to a new one
  radialGradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    0,0,300,
    260,160,100
   );
  radialGradient.addColorStop(0, c1.value);
  radialGradient.addColorStop(1, c2.value);
  ctx.fillStyle = radialGradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

didMount();
c1.oninput = c2.oninput = didUpdate;
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid };
```

```html
<input id="c1" type="color" value="#22CC22">
<input id="c2" type="color" value="#FF2222">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```